# Logging in to VM terminal?

Tags: virtual-machine, putty, git-bash

I am a fresher who joined a organisation recently, I got access to VM they gave just ip address, username & password of VM is it enough to login to terminal emulators like putty or git bash? If yes please do brief about the procedure.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's enought. In git bash you can do `ssh user@server_ip` to get in, and then you will have to put the password.

Example: `ssh sachin@192.168.1.53`